# What does the "RGB" button do on the front of my old TV?

Tags: consumer-electronics, engineering-history

JVC, AV-S280ENT.

This button exists on my 1989 TV. What exactly does it do? It seems like it would "enable RGB" for one SCART connector at a time, but what does that even mean? Why don't both have RGB if they are SCART connectors? Not that I understand why it matters either way since only one video signal can be shown on the TV at the same time, but still, I'd like to know what the button actually does.

The manual (I only have it in Dutch, and it's only for a similar model) mention nothing about it. It seems to be taken for granted that this feature/setting makes perfect sense.

At first, I thought it meant that RGB is turned on/off globally, but it seems most likely that it switched which SCART connector that currently has RGB support. Very odd to me.

(I'm always told to ask one question at a time, but the fact is that I also wonder about the "SKEW" and "S" buttons...)

[image]

Comment: Brand and model will help you get an answer.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat See update.

Comment: it's not an "RGB" button per se ... it is a button to select one of two inputs

Comment: @jsotola A button to select one or two inputs? Huh? What does that mean? You are even less clear than the TV.

Comment: i did not say `select one or two inputs`

Comment: It selects either EXT1 or EXT2. I assume those are the two possible RGB inputs.